# particular solution. tan function as RHS

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would you discover the particular solution for

> $$y'' + y = \tan(x)$$

Not really sure where to start with this one.

Would it involve a trigonometric identity?

Comment: Use variation of coefficients.

Comment: try $$-\cos(x)\ln\left(\frac{1+\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By method of Variation of Parameters, you can find that the particular solution is given by

$$Y_p = -y_1 \int \frac{y_2 \> g(x)}{W(y_1, y_2} dx + y_2 \int\frac{y_1 g(x)}{W(y_1, y_2)}dx$$

where $y_1, y_2$ are the basis functions for the fundamental set of solutions to the homogeneous problem, $g(x)$ is the non-homogeneous part, in your case $\tan(x)$, and $W$ denotes the Wronskian. This may seem strange, but the [derivation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VariationofParameters.html) is quite straightforward.

Putting everything in gives

$$Y_p = \sin x \int \cos x \tan x \> dx - \cos x \int \sin x \tan x \> dx$$
$$Y_p = -\sin x \cos x - \cos x \int (\sec x - \cos x) \> dx$$
$$ Y_p = -\sin x \cos x + \cos x \> (\> \sin x - \ln (\sec x + \tan x) \> )$$